# Appending 0 before the hexa number

Tags: x86-16, assembly

I have been instructed by my teacher to append `0` before the `hexa numbers` while writing instructions as some compilers search for `0` before the number in an instruction to differentiate it from a label. I am confused if the instruction already starts with a 0, what should be done in such a case?

For Example,

```
AND BL, 0FH
```

Is there a need of adding `0` before that hexa number or not? Please help me out. Thanks

### EDIT:

Sorry if I had not been clearer enough before. What I meant was that in the above example, a 0 is already present, do I need to convert it to,

```
AND BL, 00FH
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except for the special cases like `0` or `1`, I tend to encode my hex numbers with the full complement of digits just so it's easier to see what the intent is:

```
mov al, 09h
mov ax, 0123h
```

and so on.

For cases where the number starts with an alpha character (like `deadbeef`), I prefix it with an extra `0`.

But no, it's not usually <sup>(a)</sup> necessary to do this if your hex number already begins with a digit.

In any case, I'd be putting most numbers into an `equ` statement rather than sprinkling magic numbers throughout the code. Would you rather see:

```
mov ax, 80
```

or:

```
mov ax, lines_per_screen
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Of course, it depends on your assembler but, from memory, all the ones I've used work this way.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no need (and including more than one leading 0 is fairly unusual).

Your example is an apt one though -- without the leading `0` to tell it this was a number, the assembler would normally interpret `FH` as a symbol rather than a number.

Comment: @www.AppTec.net: Yes, that's what I was talking about when I said that including more than one leading 0 would be unusual. In other words, I'd expect to see `0FH`, but as a general rule, not `00FH`. Once in a while you see extra leading zeros, mostly to emphasize the size involved. E.g., `Red_mask = 0ff0000h, green_mask = 000ff00h, blue_mask = 00000ffh`.